# fstream requires an absolute directory in VS Code to load a file. How would I use a relative directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, fstream

I am creating files (currently in .txt form) that I would like to open using filestream. Using `file.open()` only works when I use the absolute directory (something like `D:/repos/project/resources/textfile.txt`) instead of `project/resources/textfile.txt`. This is problematic because not everyone on my team has the same file structure that I have.

I'm guessing it is a compiler thing, but I'm not sure. Here is what my build task looks like (I'm just using the default cpp vscode build task)

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind":"build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: The usual way is to stipulate that those files should be in the same directory  as your built .exe file (or a subdirectory thereof) and then use [`GetModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) to retrieve the name of that directory at runtime.

Comment: You are mistaken. It is not a "compiler thing". It would be rather silly for a compiler to prohibit, somehow, programs from opening files with relative paths. There wouldn't be much use for such a compiler. The problem is not the compiler. What proof can you show that documents what the program's current directory, such that a given relative paths exists, but the file cannot be opened? Just because `.cpp` files come from a particular directory doesn't mean that the directory the program will execute from. In fact, look at the `cwd` option, do you know what that means?

Comment: A relative path is relative to the current working directory, not relative to the location of the source file or whatever else you seem to have assumed it was relative to. If this is a file that needs to be distributed with your project, you probably want to have the build system copy the file into the target folder during compilation so that its location relative to your program is predictable.